# Android relative layout gravity fill problem

Tags: android, android-layout, height, android-relativelayout, gravity

I am trying to create a layout of 8 image-buttons that fill the screen. 

 I have the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:gravity="fill"
  android:background="@drawable/background">

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY">

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r1_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r2_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r3_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r4_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r5_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r6_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r7_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r8_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:scaleType="fitXY"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
   </LinearLayout>  
</RelativeLayout>
```

The width of the image buttons are filling the parent, but the height is not.

 How do I make them so that, their height varies to fit the screen?

 Is this to be done in java? 

If so, what is the most efficient way?

 Thank you.

Comment: try providing `android:layout_weight="1"` to each ImageButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try providing `android:layout_weight="1"` to each ImageButton.

Comment: and I just realized it's already been put up. Sorry to screw up your inbox, @Brahadeesh... :)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to do in the next way?

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r1_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r2_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r3_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r4_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r5_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r6_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r7_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/calls_r8_c1"
                 android:id="@+id/basic"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Instead of using RelativeLayout and gravity configuration?

Comment: weights'"1" or "0" are all that matter, anything greater or lesser would be replaced with 1 or 0 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="fill" android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY">

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/a" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/b" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/c" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/d" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/e" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/f" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/g" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/h" android:id="@+id/basic"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```